# Model Data Reduction in OpenGLES2.0 for Android

Tags: java, android, memory, opengl-es

I had this idea, and I don't know enough about VBOs and FloatBuffers to know if it is valid. In an attempt to reduce data in my program, I had the idea to hold face data as a single string, and break it up with String.split("/") when rendering. This would remove all redundant vertices from my data, just as a WaveFront .OBJ file does. I figure that it will only slow down the GPU a little each time it draws a face, while greatly reducing my model sizes. However, VBOs and FloatBuffers, both packed and unpacked, take a consistent array of vertex data, represented in a single float[]. It seems that OGLES2.0 wants ALL the data in one buffer, in order. So, my idea doesn't seem to be holding up.

ex:

With redundancies:

Buffer = { x1, x2, x3... x30,000 }

(Draw all faces in order, all at once)

Without:

Buffer = { x1, x2, x3... x1,000 }

fData[x] = "x/x/x x/x/x x/x/x"

(Draw each face according to the references in fData[x], one at a time)

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it ever appropriate to leave out redundant vertices in your buffers and use the .OBJs fData to assemble the faces when rendering? Why or why not?
2. If not, what are my limits? I have a model with about 1,000 vertices before redundancies are added. Can a VBO or FloatBuffer handle that many vertices (with redundancies) in Android? Roughly how many of these models could I render at once before I run out of memory?
3. If so, how do you suggest I let OGLES2.0 know where my data is in the buffer for each face? Buffer.setPosition(x)?
4. What are the generally accepted methods of model storage in Android and other flavors of OpenGL? How would YOU store each model in order to reduce the amount of data to the smallest size possible?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit: 5. Would glDrawElements solve my problem? Right now I'm using glDrawArrays. I just read a post somewhere that led me to believe that glDrawElements is better when redundant vertices exist. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. The answer was, indeed, to use glDrawElements. With glDrawElements, you assign **unique** vertices to a FloatBuffer or VBO, then assign face data to a FloatBuffer or VBO. glDrawElements takes these two Buffers and does the work for you.

```
float vertsCoords[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,          //V0
                                  -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,           //V1
                                  -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         //V2
                                   0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         //V3
                                   0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,       //V4
                                   0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,       //V5
                                  -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,       //V6
                                  -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,     //V7
                    }; 
GLubyte indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 3,              //Front face
                            5, 0, 3, 4,             //Right face
                            5, 6, 7, 4,             //Back face
                            5, 6, 1, 0,             //Upper face
                            1, 6, 7, 2,              //Left face
                            7, 4, 3, 2,             //Bottom face
                  }; 

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);       
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertsCoords);
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
```

indices[] = fData[] and vertCoords[] = vData!

Taaadaaa!

Edit: I just found this very, very dissapointing news and figured I'd share it with y'all;

Quoted from gamedevs.net. "_Walrus" says,

If you are reducing shared verticies from your draw array method(i.e, removing redundant verticies) then you will run into problems cause you wont beable to specify multiple texCoords to that one vertex. I guess this is easier to explain with a cube. with a cube, a vertex is repeated 3 times (i.e., the corner). So each face of the cube will have the exact same vertex (geometrically speaking), but each face may have a different tex Coord. When u reduce the reducency when moving to index list then you run into the problem of multiple tex coord for one vertex. Opengl Doesnt support multiple texCoord for one vertex (with respect to index list), nor does it with any other array (ie., normals, colors...). So i guess the rule is: when decimating ur geometry, only remove redunant verticies that share, normals, position, texCoord..etc.

=(